# How to get a nested response data from json python

Tags: python, json, api

I call an API and this my JSON response:

```
{'data': [{
   'id': 'd-1225959', 
   'startTime': '2022-12-30T00:00:00.000Z', 
   'endTime': '2022-12-30T23:59:00.000Z', 
   'checkedInAt': None, 
   'checkedOutAt': None, 
   'status': 'PENDING', 

'space': {
   'id': 'd-4063963', 
   'name': '082', 
   'type': 'DESK', 
   'createdAt': '2021-07-06T11:48:57.000Z', 
   'updatedAt': '2021-07-06T11:48:57.000Z', 
   'isAvailable': False, 
   'assignedTo': None, 
   'locationId': '133778', 
   'floorId': '41681', 
   'floorName': 'Car Park', 
   'neighborhoodId': '92267', 
   'neighborhoodName': 'NEI1'}}
```

I'm struggling to get the `'space'` `'id'` and `'name'` extracted out if I do a nested python loop like so it only returns the headers like `'id'` and `'name'` not the values held within.

```
for order in response['data']:
        print(order['id'])
        print(order['startTime'])
        print(order['endTime'])
        print(order['checkedInAt'])
        print(order['checkedOutAt'])
        print(order['status'])
        print(order['space'])
        for doc in response['space']:
            print(doc['id'], doc['name'])
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your sample data is not valid Python.

Comment: Your JSON response has unmatched `[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for doc in response['space']:` will iterate over the keys in `response['space']` dict, i.e. `doc` will be `str`.

You want to do `doc = response['space']` instead and then `print(doc['id'])`. or directly `print(response['space']['id'])`.

Note, you may want to use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to avoid `KeyError`.

```
# if response dict has no 'space' key, return empty dict.
# if no 'id' key - return None
space_id = response.get('space', {}).get('id')
```

Comment: Would that look something like this?
`spacedata = response['space'].get(['id'])
            print(spacedata)`

Comment: Check my updated answer